# Excel filtermode "Out of memory" error

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I'm getting a very strange error when I type the following line into an Excel VBA script:

```
If ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then
```

As soon as I hit `Enter`, I get an `Out of Memory` message and the text disappears leaving a blank line.

The module that I am editing has 102 lines and Excel is the only foreground program open (the Task Manager says it is using a total of 513Mb).  There is also an additional 803Mb of physical memory free.  I have also tried closing Excel, waiting a minute or to and then reopening Excel.

`Debug.Print ActiveSheet.FilterMode` also gives an out of memory error.  However, both the line `If 1=2 Then` and adding `ActiveSheet.FilterMode` to the Watch list work correctly.

As I've never seen this happen before, does anyone have any ideas?

**Solved** (sort of):

A previous version of the same workbook will allow me to add `FilterMode` to the code.  I did save the bad version and, even after rebooting the computer, it exhibits the same problem.  It therefore appears that the problem is with the workbook and not Excel.